# Rebuilding QuickFixJ with modified FIXT11.xml

Tags: java, quickfixj

I  have added `NoLegs` group to my `FIXT11.xml` , I want to rebuild my quickFixJ.

Referring to [this](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.0.0//installation.html#build),
I have downloaded quickfixJ from [here](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj).

now i have replaced older `FIXT11.xml` with new one at `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\QuickFixJ\quickfixj-master\quickfixj-messages\quickfixj-messages-fixt11\src\main\resources` location

Running command `mvn package` at root directory, generates SNAPSHOT jar with only META-INF folder with no classes folder.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to go deeper.

There is folder `quickfixj-distribution\target` in root directory. You can find `org.quickfixj-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip` in it. This file contains various jars.

Comment: yes there is a folder `quickfixj-distribution` but there is no target folder because i have run the command `mvn package` over `quickfixj-master\quickfixj-messages\quickfixj-messages-fixt11` just to create messages jar

Comment: Simplest way is to run `mvn package` from root folder, but if you don't want then look in other folders. `quickfixj-core` is good place to start.

Comment: okay, since i have not found this jar, shall i run `mvn package` over `quickfixj-master\quickfixj-core` or `quickfixj-master\ ` ? after replacing my FIXT11.xml with older one

Comment: I did it in quickfixj-master and got required jar. Be prepared to wait around 15 minutes or turn of tests.

Comment: it is giving error as `[ERROR] /C:/Users/admin/Desktop/QuickFixJ/quickfixj-master (1)/quickfixj-master/quickfixj-core/target/generated-sources/quickfix/fix50sp2/PositionReport.java:[3465,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LegSecurityIDSource
[ERROR] location: package quickfix.field` , i have added `LegGroup` inside `TradeCaptureReport`

Comment: Now i am running with `FIXT11.xml` from [here](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/edit/master/spec/FIXT11.xml)  without any changes, it is giving error as `/C:/Users/admin/Desktop/QuickFixJ/quickfixj-master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/Session.java:[1428,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable SessionStatus
[ERROR] location: class quickfix.Session` . any idea ?